# Make custom button appear on top of React Native Navigation Bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to create a navigation bar with a large custom button in the middle. The routing and everything works, but the button gets cut off at the border of the navigation bar component. How can I make it, so that the button displays on top? I tried zIndex, but that did not work for me. Thank you.

```
const HomeIcon = <Icon name="time-outline" size={40} color="#829a9a" />;
const ScanIcon = <Icon name="qr-code-outline" size={60} color="#829a9a" />;
const GiftsIcon = <Icon name="gift-outline" size={40} color="#829a9a" />;

const App: () => Node = () => {
    const customTabBarStyle = {
        activeTintColor: '#3ED77C',
        inactiveTintColor: '#829a9a',
        allowFontScaling: true,
        labelStyle: { fontSize: 14, paddingTop: 5 },
        tabStyle: { paddingTop: 5 },
        style: { height: 70},
      }
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={customTabBarStyle}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}
                 options={{
                   tabBarLabel: 'Aktuell',
                   tabBarIcon: () => (HomeIcon),
                 }} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Scan" component={ScanScreen}
                options= {({navigation}) => ({
                   tabBarLabel: 'Scanner',
                   tabBarButton: (props) => (
                    <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Scan')}
                        buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
                        icon={ScanIcon}
                      />)
                 })} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Gifts" component={GiftsScreen}
                options={{
                   tabBarLabel: 'Prämien',
                   tabBarIcon: () => (GiftsIcon),
                 }} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
      bottom: 30,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      height: 120,
      width: 120,
      backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
      borderRadius: 100,
  },
});

export default App;
```

See image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB2C1.png

Comment: It appears the button (along with text) is too large for the navbar which has a fixed height. Maybe you set its position to `absolute`, add `background-radius: 50%` so pops out of the navbar over the screen a bit.

Answer (score 2):

**I already made similer button check this example->**

[image]

youtube link-
https://youtu.be/vIWi7eLZomk

you can checkout this example
https://github.com/vishalpwr/bottom-tab-navigation

```
const BottomTab = ({ type, color, size = 24, isFocused, index }) => {
  const icon = index == 0 ? 'home' : 'heart';
  const gradient = index == 1;
  return (
    <View>
      {gradient ? (
        <LinearGradient
          colors={[Colors.light, Colors.dark]}
          start={{ x: isFocused ? 0 : 1, y: 0 }} end={{ x: isFocused ? 1 : 0, y: 0 }}
          style={styles.middleIcon}>
          <AppIcon name={'shopping-basket'} type={type} size={size} color={'white'} />
        </LinearGradient>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.icon}>
          <AppIcon name={icon} type={type} size={size} color={color} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBar={(props) => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Shop" component={ShopScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Favorite" component={FavoriteScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const MyTabBar = ({ state, descriptors, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={styles.bottomBar}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const isFocused = state.index === index;
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          })
          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        }

        const color = isFocused ? Colors.dark : Colors.gray;

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            onPress={onPress}
            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
            accessibilityRole="button"
          >
            <BottomTab
              type={index !== 1 ? Icons.MaterialCommunityIcons : Icons.FontAwesome5}
              index={index}
              isFocused={isFocused}
              size={24}
              color={color}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottomBar: {
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  middleIcon: {
    bottom: 18,
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.6,
    elevation: 8,
  }
});
```

Comment: you can also use `import {BottomTabBar} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'` to render the default tab bar and add something extra to it, or read the props

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to prevent the ScanIcon from being cut off from the top.

```
navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        let iconName = require('./{{PATH}}/abc.png');
        return (
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                width: '102%',
                height: '100%',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: COLOR.AppTheme,
              }}>
              <Image
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  bottom: 5,
                }}
                source={iconName}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            </View>
        );
    },
 },
```

Clear and simple. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bit late, but just in case someone still need it, you can just add custom comp. when you define the "Tab.Screen" by simply adding the "headerRight" or "headerLeft" if you need it.
Example with you code:

```
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}
             options={{
               tabBarLabel: 'Aktuell',
               tabBarIcon: () => (HomeIcon),
               // HERE <---
               headerRight: () => (    
                    <Button title="Log In" />
                   ) 
             }} 
             />
```