# How to create curve in react navigation 5 bottom tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-svg

[I want to create bottom tab like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwYUl.png)

I want to implement this design in react navigation 5 bottom tab navigator.
I'm using createBottomTabNavigator, Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can see these answer

[Make custom button appear on top of React Native Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706716/make-custom-button-appear-on-top-of-react-native-navigation-bar/66712412#66712412)

here I already answered how to make bottom tab like your requirement

Comment: Actually i want the curve below the home button as per the image.

Comment: You should use react-native-svg by this you can add curve.